# Passing token to ArcGIS Server REST service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-rest-api, authentication

I'm using .NET code to submit GET and POST requests to secured REST services served up by our internal ArcGIS Server 10.4.

How should I pass the security token?

Perhaps I can just add it as a querystring parameter but I do not know the parameter key.

I found documentation explaining the what and why of ArcGIS Server tokens but not how to actually pass them in a request. I have the url for obtaining a token. I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: The [documentation](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/acquiring-arcgis-tokens.htm) explains how the token request is sent,  in a POST to an HTTPS port. There are multiple possible encoding options. As with all the other capabilities of the REST API, the best way to find out how it works is to enable network logging in your JavaScript console of choice and hit the API from a web client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**For Post Request**
You send it over inside a form in the body with the key `token` and the value is the token you received from this [`document explaining how to get token`](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/acquiring-arcgis-tokens.htm)

**For Get Request**
You can send them over via a query parameter attached to the url

```
https://services1.arcgis.com/dis-mine/arcgis/rest/services/my-name/FeatureServer/0/query?where=blahblah*outfields=*&token=YOURTOKEN&f=json
```

Comment: how to pass token with arcgis wmtsp tile map server?

Comment: Thanks i am able to get the tiles with last token paraemeter.